# Font size in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, tocloft

I get a problem when creating toc with my style, I want all font size is normalsize, but it doesn't work for the chapter. here my code :

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\large\bfseries\fillast }{BAB \thechapter}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-0.275in}{20pt}
\chapterfont{\normalfont\centering}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering\normalfont}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
```

and the result:

[image]

How to set the font size of the chapter to normalsize?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using the `tocloft` package, right? If so, have you tried the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
```

which should set the font size of chapter-level entries in the TOC

Comment: yes, I use the tocloft package,

yes, I have tried that istruction and give the same result

Comment: According to your MWE, you've been using the `\normalfont` instruction inside `\cftchapfont` -- which affects the font style but not its size -- rather than `\normalize`. That's why I suggested you try `\normalsize`. Oh, I've updated the answer to show that you should probably also specify `\bfseries` as an argument to `\cftchapfont`.

Comment: yes, it's running well in miktex. but my problem is in lyx.now, I have solved my problem in lyx : change manually the chapter by right click the capter -> text style -> (setting) -> apply. and without any change my code above in latex preable. Thanks Marco :-)

Comment: Glad you found a solution!